# How do you clear pending updates in Power Bi?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I was pulling data from a Sharepoint Server and accidentally chose "Edit" rather than "Load."  I didn't actually make any changes.  But now Power BI keeps telling me there are pending changes that have no been applied. Every time I try to pull any data from Sharepoint it fails because first its trying to update something, and it can't, making Power BI completely unusable to me.  Surely there is a way to clear the pending changes, isn't there?

By the way, I deleted the queries. And the stupid junk software is still saying "there are changes pending to be applied to your queries."  What queries? I deleted them all!  Actually the message appears after I begin running a new query.

Comment: Still not possible. Please vote for the idea here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9545490-discard-query-changes

Answer (score 3):

Incredibly, after developing Power BI Desktop for over 2 years, there is still no way to undo a change in the Query Editor window.  Your only options are:

1. manually change all the Queries back to exactly the same state they were in when you opened the Query Editor. This sometimes works.
2. close the file without saving.

Comment: Those guys.....

Comment: Almost +2 years (sighs).  Hack #1 doesnt seem to work any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 year to that. 
I am just starting to use BI and I find the simplest changes a pain

1. Created a report as an "Import" and then found out that the simple option of switching to a Live Query is incredibly cumbersome. This should be a simple switch in the report property!!!!

   2. As was reported here. If you have an error in a Query, you will keep getting a Warning about "Apply Changes" but that will fail due to the error and there is no option to Edit or even Undo the Change!!!
   3. Am I missing something, or is there really no NEW option in BI. This has to be an oversight on my part because I can't believe that I really need to start a new BI instance and set a new datasource in order to create a new report.

I will keep trying to get a handle on this product, but it is in desperate need of a professional UI review.